# Group a Group in SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, group-by

I have the following Query:

```
SELECT Inspections.Pipe_Segment_Reference,
(COUNT(*) * Conditions.structural_grade) AS Structural_Rating
FROM (
    SELECT Inspections.Pipe_Segment_Reference, Conditions.structural_grade
    FROM Conditions
    INNER JOIN Inspections
    ON Conditions.InspectionID = Inspections.InspectionID
    WHERE Conditions.structural_grade IS NOT NULL
)
GROUP BY Inspections.Pipe_Segment_Reference, Conditions.structural_grade;
```

Which Outputs

```
22, 2
22, 4
79, 2
79, 5
79, 3
```

I want to further GROUP by Pipe_Segment_Reference to get output of

```
22, 6
79, 10
```

I tried adding an additional Select around the query above but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with adding an additional `SELECT` around your working query.  Try this...

```
SELECT
    DerivedYourInitialQuery.Pipe_Segment_Reference,
    SUM(DerivedYourInitialQuery.Structural_Rating) AS NewTotal
FROM
    (
    SELECT Inspections.Pipe_Segment_Reference,
    (COUNT(*) * Conditions.structural_grade) AS Structural_Rating
    FROM (
        SELECT Inspections.Pipe_Segment_Reference, Conditions.structural_grade
        FROM Conditions
        INNER JOIN Inspections
        ON Conditions.InspectionID = Inspections.InspectionID
        WHERE Conditions.structural_grade IS NOT NULL
    )
    GROUP BY Inspections.Pipe_Segment_Reference, Conditions.structural_grade
    ) DerivedYourInitialQuery
GROUP BY
    DerivedYourInitialQuery.Pipe_Segment_Reference
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you do group by only on Pipe_Segment_Reference in a additional select/ sub query?

or may be this:

```
SELECT Inspections.Pipe_Segment_Reference,
COUNT(*) AS Structural_Rating
FROM (
    SELECT Inspections.Pipe_Segment_Reference, Conditions.structural_grade
    FROM Conditions
    INNER JOIN Inspections
    ON Conditions.InspectionID = Inspections.InspectionID
    WHERE Conditions.structural_grade IS NOT NULL
)
GROUP BY Inspections.Pipe_Segment_Reference;
```

Comment: The query runs but does not output the correct values as this part of query needs to be included:  (COUNT(*) * Conditions.structural_grade) AS Structural_Rating

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

SELECT

xxx1.Pipe_Segment_Reference,

sum( nfield or selectResult2 ) as xname

from xtable1 xxx1

GROUP BY 1

having. (condition )

order by 1